Padding Oracle - Decrypted Text Decreasing
I am using the article "Oracle Padding Attack
by Mahmoud Jadaan" article to understand the padding oracle attack.

In my personal github project is the code that performs all the decryption etc.:
    def cbc_decrypt(self, ciphertext):
        """
        Decrypts the given ciphertext using AES in Cipher Block Chaining (CBC) mode.
    
        :param ciphertext: (bytes) The input ciphertext to be decrypted.
        :return: (bytes) The decrypted plaintext.
        :raises ValueError: If the input ciphertext is not of type 'bytes'.
        :raises Exception: If an error occurs during decryption.
        """
        if not isinstance(ciphertext, bytes):
            raise ValueError("Input ciphertext must be bytes")
    
        try:
            data, iv = ciphertext[self.bs:], ciphertext[:self.bs]
            cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
            decrypted_data = cipher.decrypt(data)
            return unpad(decrypted_data, self.bs)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Decryption error: {e}")
            raise

The issue is that when I show the values that are being passed to function and the decrypted text I get this

I am not sure why the decrypted value is decreasing. At start it was 16 bytes and then decreasing.
From the figure, is my assumption wrong or may be the decrypted value be different from what I have inferred? I am assuming it to be the intermediate value.

What produced the picture is unclear. It's not the code shown (even if that piece of code is involved).
